# Pycharm disconnecting from remote ssh interpreter

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm 2018.3.4 proffesional on windows. Every time the connection to the SSH interpreter is lost even for a second, the program crashes with error -1. Is there a way to persistently connect via SSH interpreter?

I have seen similar problem in older version of Pycharm:
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071612/pycharm-remote-processes-finish-when-connection-breaks). There seem to be no solution when I set the check if alive to a high number. Is there any other solution?

Thank you!